# How to print nth index from vector of vectors

Tags: vector, indexing, clojure, lisp

I have a homework problem that requires me to print (in a vector) a specified nth index from a vector of vectors. For examples, if I enter `[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8] [9 10 11 12]` and enter my function specifying the nth index 1, my result has to be `[2 6 10]`.

Very confused, not good at Clojure, just a Java/Python person.

I've already tried using a function that accepts vector and a variable to serve as the nth. But it returns the whole vectors AND the value entered for x.

```
(defn column [vector x] 
     (cond
     (empty? vector)
     nil 
     :else
        (column (nth vector x))))
```

If I enter:
`user ==> column vector 0`

Result is this:
`[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8] [9 10 11 12]
0`

Instead of:
`[1 5 9]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idiomatic clojure way of solving this would be with the use of map

```clj
(def v [[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8] [9 10 11 12]])

(defn column [coll pos]
  (map #(nth % pos) coll))
```

the `nth` function gives the nth element in the vector. The map function will iterate over each of the inner vectors and call `nth` on it with the given column value.

The result will be a sequence of value from the required column.

Comment: Dont worry it takes time to understand the various idioms of clojure and FP. If you found the answer helpful I would really appreciate if you accepted the answer.